# Discord.py cooldownmapping within on_message event

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is my code for cooldown per user on when they earn xp its supposed to have a 6 second cooldown on when they gain xp on the server:

```py
class expclass():
    def __init__(self, message):
        self._cd = commands.CooldownMapping.from_cooldown(1.0, 6.0, commands.BucketType.user)
        self.message = message
    async def exp_stuff(self):
        message = self.message
        bucket = self._cd.get_bucket(message)
        retry_after = bucket.update_rate_limit()
        if retry_after:
            with open("users.json", "r") as f:
                users = json.load(f)
            await update_data(users, message.author)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, 1)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
            await rank_up(users, message.author, message)
            with open("users.json", "w") as f:
                json.dump(users, f)
```

i cannot seem to get if retry after to work and there isnt a lot of information on it so im not really sure what i have done wrong as it hasn't shown any errors when it has run for a while
I call this class from within the on_message event

```
    obj = expclass(message)
    await obj.exp_stuff()
```

Thanks in advance and i'd appreciate any feedback on my code